# Google Earth in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps

I am in the process of using Google Earth in an ASP.NET MVC app.

Are there any references you could guide me on integrating both together? Is there any jQuery plugin for Google Earth?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Answer (score -1):

References:

- http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

jQuery Plugin:

- http://labs.mario.ec/jquery-gmap/

Comment: Hello, that was Google Maps and not Google Earth.